# what does "Error: constructors may not be cv-qualified?

Tags: c++, class

I think it is because of the code I wrote below. But I couldn't solve it.

```
classname::smt() {;}

classname::smt1(int x, double y, string name)
{
    x = xprivate;
    y = yprivate;
    name = nameprivate;
}
```

Comment: "cv" here means "const and/or volatile".  Do you have one of these qualifier in the declaration of a constructor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means you can't have code that does this:

```
class classname
{
    classname() const
    classname() volatile
    classname() const volatile
};
```

cv-qualifers apply to storage and to methods, not to constructors or destructors (because you still have to initialize cv-qualified storage).

Comment: The interesting question is why. It would be useful, instead of declaring all-`const` fields, to just `=delete` non-const constructors.